# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.security.model.UserRequest

Tags: java, jpa

Am retriving `UserRequest` object from DB using JPA Query as following.

```
@Query("SELECT req.supervisorEmail from User u, UserRequest as req WHERE u.username = req.userRequestName and req.userRequestRole= '4' and u.active=true")
 public List<UserRequest> getSupervisorEmailIds();
```

Am having the `UserRequest` POJO class as follows.

```
public class UserRequest implements Identifiable<Long>, LazilyLoadable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

@Column(name = "supervisor_email")
private String supervisorEmail;

@Column(name="user_request_name")
private String userRequestName;

@Column(name="user_request_role")
private String userRequestRole;

}
```

when am trying to iterating over the `UserRequest` object am getting the `ClassCastException` for the below code.

```
List<UserRequest> supervisorEmailIds = userService.getSupervisorEmailIds();
for(UserRequest s: supervisorEmailIds) { // throwing exception on this line.
if(s!=null) {
System.out.println("Printing -->"+s.getSupervisorEmail());
}
System.out.println("Null error");
}
```

Following is the error am getting.

```
2019-02-22 00:34:26,719 [http-9191-1] ERROR         com.cat.pscs.api.controller.BaseController:  83 - Unhandled exception while processing request for URL : http://localhost:9191/security/users/get-supervisor-emailids with exception : java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.cat.pscs.security.model.UserRequest
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.cat.pscs.security.model.UserRequest
    at com.cat.pscs.security.controller.UserController.getSupervisorEmailIds(UserController.java:320)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that below line returns UserRequestList? I think it returns list of strings

```
List<UserRequest> supervisorEmailIds = userService.getSupervisorEmailIds();
```

just change your sql query that returns list of UserRequest object .

Answer (score 2):

Your query returns list of `String`, while you expect to get list of `UserRequest`. Changing query as follow should do the job:

```
@Query("SELECT req from User u, UserRequest as req WHERE u.username = req.userRequestName and req.userRequestRole= '4' and u.active=true")
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `@Query` you wrote

```
SELECT req.supervisorEmail from User u, UserRequest as req...
```

I suppose `supervisorEmail` is a `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` table column.
You're extracting only a single `String` column.

If you want `UserRequest`(s), you need

```
SELECT req from User u, UserRequest as req...
```